# AngularJS one file at a time upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I am working on a AngularJS file upload controller. In this case the user should be able to upload a JPG containing all EXIF information in the file.

However, these are big (5mb+) jpg's send to a remote API. To prevent the server going down from 100+ file uploads (which is not unlikely) I want all the uploads to happen synchronously.

I am using the following ng-upload lib which states this fiddle uploads synchronously:
https://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/2vq88rfs/136/

However, when I run it with 5 files, they all get uploaded at once and I don't know how to change it so that the forEach uploads (see code example) the next file after the previous file has been uploaded.

```
angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
            data: {file: file}
        });
```

Can someone tell me how this can be done synchronously?

Comment: "However, when I run it with 5 files, they all get uploaded at once and I don't know how to change it so that the forEach uploads (see code example) the next file after the previous file has been uploaded." So you want them to be uploaded "synchronously" not "asynchronously"?

Comment: Ah yeah, exactly! I will edit it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a queue that control sending request

step 1: create a variable to control the execution

```
this.indexFile = undefined;
```

step 2: Register a $watch to watch this.indexFile

```
   _attachListener() {
        let vm = this;
        vm._scope.$watch('vm.indexFile', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if(newValue !== oldValue){
                vm._attachFile();
            }
        });
    }
```

step 3: code to send files

```
_attachFile(){
    if(this.indexFile < this.files.length){
        if (!this.files[this.indexFile].progress) {
              this.service.attach(this.files[this.indexFile])
                .then()
                .catch()
                .finally(()=>{
                    this.files[this.indexFile].progress = 100;
                    this.indexFile++ ;
              });
         }else{
            this.indexFile++ ;
         }
    }
}
```

step 4: start variable to control the execution

```
startIndexFile() {
    let vm = this;
    vm.indexFile = 0;
}
```

setp 5: html code to start the upload

```
<button type="button" ng-click="vm.startIndexFile()"></button>
```